# How to find which object id caused an event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, getelementbyid

I have a page with javascript.
The Javascript has a function that is called by 2 different elements on click:

1.Check box is clicked:

```
$('#chkShowAll').click(
    function () {          
        myself.MyFunction(myself._findjcontrol("lblMID").text(), this);
    }
);
```

2.  Table row is clicked:

```
    myself.get_DataTable().find('tbody > tr').click(
         function(){  
              myself.MyFunction($(this).data("ID"), this);
         }
    );
```

This is the function call:

```
this.MyFunction = function (id, objectClicked) {

//here I need to get the ID of the clicked element, so I can do different logic:

if(checkbox is clicked){
  // do this
}
if(tablerow is clicked){
  //do this
}
```

How can I accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 0):

`this` in javascript denotes how the function was called and not how it was defined (untill you define an Arrow Function)

The function callback of the click event will take the `function( Event eventObject )` which has the event information. the `eventObject .Target` would have the element which raised the event.